# What is the bean ID of spring bean implements an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

When the bean is createt for a class as `MyBean` the bean id is `myBean` but **what will be the bean ID if I create the service bean from an interface like below?**

```
@Service
public class ProfileServiceImpl implements ProfileService
```

When I try to access the bean as `@profileService` thymeleaf gives the below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'profileService' is defined
```

All this time I'm using this bean by `autowiring` to the controller. But at the moment I need to access this from the `thymeleaf`.

My thymeleaf code segment

```
 <div th:unless="${@profileService.isMe(user)}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Spring creates a Bean Definition from a @Service or @Component annotation, it will by default create an id for the bean by lowercasing the first letter of the Class Name.  If you want to override that the behavior, you can provide an alternative id in the annotation, eg. @Service("profileService").

Regarding what you are experiencing with the Repository - by default Spring looks for a custom implementation of a Repository by appending "Impl" to the Repository Interface name.  If it finds it, it will not create a default implementation.  So, if you had `UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepository` instead of `UserRepositoryImpl extends DatatablesCriteriasRepository` than Spring wouldn't have created the `userRepository` bean. Addtionally, if you add `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation to the `UserRepository` interface, that will suppress the creation of the `userRepository` bean.

However, `UserRepositoryImpl` really should be implementing `UserRepository`.  If it really is intended to extend `DatatablesCriteriasRepository`, than it should be nameed `DatatablesCriteriasRepositoryImpl`.  Having `UserRepsitoryImpl` extend `DatatablesCriteriasRepository` is indication of a problem in the design.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But related to the code design, i posted my issue in the separate question. Hope you can have a look at it too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467886/implementing-crudrepository-in-spring-whats-the-best-design-i-should-follow

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String name : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

This test revealed some interesting outcomes.

**service beans**

Service beans are named after the concrete class name regardless of the interface.

```
@Service
public class ProfileServiceImpl implements ProfileService
```

ie. `profileServiceImpl` in the above question.

**Repository beans**

Further Repository beans are something more interesting. Below is my crud repository interface without any annotations.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, DatatablesCriteriasRepository<User>{
```

And I created an implementation of the `UserRepositoryImpl` for the `DatatablesCriteriasRepository` as below without any annotations.

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements DatatablesCriteriasRepository<User>
```

these two included two beans with IDs `userRepository` `userRepositoryImpl` respectively.