# Implementing CrudRepository in Spring. What's the best design I should follow?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-data

I have the User Repository extend from the CrudRepository as below

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, DatatablesCriteriasRepository<User>
```

`DatatablesCriteriasRepository` has a function which need to be implmented separately for different repositories.

So I created the repository implementation class like this. In the `impl` package.

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements DatatablesCriteriasRepository<User>
```

Please note this is to implement the functions in `DatatablesCriteriasRepository` only. I dont want to override the default functionalities presented in `CrudRepository` by the framework.

But If I do something like this, it will suit more in the code design, as `UserRepositoryImpl` actually implements `UserRepository` as the name suggests.

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository
```

But again this will force me to extend all the functions in the UserRepository interface. How can I solve this issue by the way in a good code design?

Can the `UserRepositoryImpl` has this name while it implements `DatatablesCriteriasRepository`?

Comment: What is your backing store? What do you need that the default implementation doesn't provide?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for pointing it out. So I'm doing it in the right way am I. :)

Comment: @chrylis I want to implement the custom search for the Dandelion Datatables's `DatatablesCriterias` object. Backing store is MySQL DB.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your first solution is the right one, is conform to the documented way of doing, and works fine. Why are you searching for a different solution?

Comment: @JBNizet I posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457834/what-is-the-bean-id-of-spring-bean-implements-an-interface and within the answer the person who answered it mentioned that my code design is not in the proper way. So I had a doubt about my code design and posted this question to get the correct view.

Comment: @JBNizet The main problem I had is regarding the naming. can `UserRepositoryImpl ` has that name while it really implements `DatatablesCriteriasRepository`

Comment: Yes, it can. Why couldn't it? You're doing as the documentation says you should, and it works. You should trust the official documentation more than a random StackOverflow user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Spring's repositories custom implementations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) documentation provides the way to implement this as @JBNizet pointed it to me.

Extract from the documentation is as follows.

*Interface for custom repository functionality*

```
interface UserRepositoryCustom {
  public void someCustomMethod(User user);
}
```

*Implementation of custom repository functionality*

```
class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}
```

*Changes to the your basic repository interface*

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {

  // Declare query methods here
}
```

Comment: What if I'm following the dependency inversion principle where UserRepository interface is in a domain module and UserRepositoryImpl is in a persistence module with spring data dependencies. Persistence module depends on domain. How can it be done with spring data?