# Spring Transactional + EnableTransactionManagement = BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm currently trying to learn Spring that's why I'm not using Spring Boot at the moment.

I'm trying to use the @Transactional annotation on one of my @Repository methods. I added EnableTransactionManagement in my Main class, but I get a BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException error when I run my app. If I remove either @Transactional or @EnableTransactionManagement, the app runs fine (but the function doesn't work as there's no commit).

Here is the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'messageRepository' is expected to be of type 'com.cypherf.repository.MessageRepository' but was actually of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy25'
```

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Main class

```
package com.cypherf;
import com.cypherf.model.Message;
import com.cypherf.repository.MessageRepository;
import com.cypherf.service.MessageService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestSpringApplication {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSpringApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestSpringApplication.class);
        TestSpringApplication app = ctx.getBean(TestSpringApplication.class);
        logger.info("Running app...");
        app.run(args);
        //TestSpringApplication app = context.getBean(TestSpringApplication.class);
        //TestSpringApplication app = new TestSpringApplication();
        //app.run(args);

    }

    public void run(String... args) {
        messageRepository.mrSave(new Message("Message one"));
        messageRepository.mrSave(new Message("Message two"));
        messageService.printAllMessages();

        messageRepository.mrSaveTransactional(new Message("Message two"));
        messageService.printAllMessages();

//        System.out.println("BEANS:");
//        List<String> beans = Arrays.asList(context.getBeanDefinitionNames());
//        beans.forEach(bean -> System.out.println(bean));
    }
}
```

MessageRepository

```
package com.cypherf.repository;
import com.cypherf.model.Message;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.cypherf.service.MessageService;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class MessageRepository implements CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
    @Autowired
    PersistenceUtil pu;

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageRepository.class);

    public void mrSave(Message message) {
        EntityManager em = pu.getEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(message);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("here");
        }
        catch (PersistenceException e) {
            System.err.printf("%s already exists%n", message);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println();
            em.close();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void mrSaveTransactional(Message message) {
        logger.info("MessageRepository.mrSaveTransactional()");
        pu.getEntityManager().persist(message);
    }

    public List<Message> getAll() {
        EntityManager em = pu.getEntityManager();
        List<Message> messages = em.createQuery("from Message", Message.class).getResultList();
        em.close();
        return messages;
    }

    [...]
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.community.dialect.H2LegacyDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./spring</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.cypherf.model.Message"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467886/implementing-crudrepository-in-spring-whats-the-best-design-i-should-follow) helps

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a bit of research, for @Transational to work, the @Service/@Repository in which it is declared (at class or method-level) needs to implement an interface (in my case it implements CrudRepository<Message, Long>) and all its methods need to be declared in that interface (you cannot declare new methods). Then you autowire this interface instead of the custom class, in my case, instead of:

```
@Autowired
private MessageRepository messageRepository;
```

I'm doing:

```
@Autowired
private CrudRepository<Message, Long> messageRepository;
```

This is because of the way Spring uses proxies (I didn't understand the details tbh).